# glVertex3f Scaling issues

Tags: c++, opengl

New to OpenGL so take it easy please. I've been tasked with using GLFont to render text in my school project, the render method of which I've pasted below. I've used `glOrtho` to set the origin to the top left corner of the window but this causes issues with GLFont rendering characters upside down. What I need to do is scale in the `y` by `-1` I believe, but I can't figure out how to change the renderer below to do that. Any ideas?

```
void GLFont::RenderText (const char* String, float x, float y, float z, float size)
{
    //Return if we don't have a valid glFont
    if (!ok)
    {
        throw GLFontError::InvalidFont();
    }

    //Get length of string
    int Length = strlen(String);

    //Begin rendering quads
    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP);

    //Loop through characters
    for (int i = 0; i < Length; i++)
    {
        //Get pointer to glFont character
        GLFONTCHAR *Char = &Font.Char[(int)String[i] - Font.IntStart];

        float dx = Char->dx*size;
        float dy = Char->dy*size;

        //Specify vertices and texture coordinates
        glTexCoord2f(Char->tx1, Char->ty2);
        glVertex3f(x, y - dy, z);
        glTexCoord2f(Char->tx1, Char->ty1);
        glVertex3f(x, y, z);
        glTexCoord2f(Char->tx2, Char->ty2);
        glVertex3f(x + dx, y - dy, z);
        glTexCoord2f(Char->tx2, Char->ty1);
        glVertex3f(x + dx, y, z);

        //Move to next character
        x += dx;
    }

    //Stop rendering quads
    glEnd();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of scaling, I suggest inverting 'char->ty1' and 'char->ty2' in your code:

```
//Specify vertices and texture coordinates
glTexCoord2f(Char->tx1, Char->ty1);
glVertex3f(x, y - dy, z);
glTexCoord2f(Char->tx1, Char->ty2);
glVertex3f(x, y, z);
glTexCoord2f(Char->tx2, Char->ty1);
glVertex3f(x + dx, y - dy, z);
glTexCoord2f(Char->tx2, Char->ty2);
glVertex3f(x + dx, y, z);
```

It will result in inverted texture mapping through y axis.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately this doesn't work, breaks the code completely and nothing renders. Had hoped there was something else I'd missed completely but I think it's just a poor implementation :(

Comment: Sorry, I'm correcting my answer. I need to wake up ;)

Comment: My thoughts being that it might be possible to do the inversion when the font is being read in?

Comment: Maye I was not clear in my edited answer, so I added corrected code. The principle is that assuming y-dy is the top of the quad, you should map it with char->ty1, and y is the bottom of the quad, associated with ty2. It will invert mapping on y axis compared with you code.

Comment: And by the way, your suggestion to invert when reading font description seems a correct solution as well.

Comment: Ahhh, my fault, I need to go to sleep. You're totally right, I wasn't thinking about it properly. Worked perfectly doing the inversion as per your example, awesome! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Simply flip the projection, i.e. swap the values you hand to the `top` and `bottom` parameters of `glOrtho`. If you've got culling enabled you also must set the culling winding into the opposite direction.